# C++ Entry Point code; identifier '___' is undefined

Tags: c++, identifier

I am fairly new to C++ and am trying to create an entry point for my project in Visual Studio 2015. However, I keep receiving an error that the "identifier " " is undefined. Here is my code:

```
#include "formMain.h"
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int _stdcall WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPInst, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{

formMain frm;
frm.ShowDialog();


return 0;
}
```

The error is referring to the section `"formMain frm;"`, where it says identifier "formMain" is undefined.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is the declaration of formMain placed in some namespace?

Comment: First, terminology. This is not the machine code level entry point. It's a Microsoft specific alternative to the standard `main` startup function. The problem with undefined identifier is not related to that, but still, you would do well by changing to a standard C++ `main` startup function (with Microsoft tools you then have to change the **entry point** to `mainCRTStartup` in the linker settings). Re the problem, possibly there's a namespace.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to add my actual namespace {ProjectName} to the namespace above.